# How to access storage areas when libraries are used?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I am testing storage areas to see exactly the efficiency aspects of this and I have trouble finding the storage on the disk for the contract/library combination.

Here is the code -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

import "./Set.sol";

contract d3 {
    Set.Data knownValues;

    function register(uint value) public {
        // The library functions can be called without a
        // specific instance of the library, since the
        // "instance" will be the current contract.
        require(Set.insert(knownValues, value));
    }
    function contains(uint value) view public returns (bool) {
        return Set.contains(knownValues, value);
    }
    // In this contract, we can also directly access knownValues.flags, if we want.
}

pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

library Set {
  // We define a new struct datatype that will be used to
  // hold its data in the calling contract.
  struct Data { mapping(uint => bool) flags; }

  // Note that the first parameter is of type "storage
  // reference" and thus only its storage address and not
  // its contents is passed as part of the call.  This is a
  // special feature of library functions.  It is idiomatic
  // to call the first parameter `self`, if the function can
  // be seen as a method of that object.
  function insert(Data storage self, uint value)
      public
      returns (bool)
  {
      if (self.flags[value])
          return false; // already there
      self.flags[value] = true;
      return true;
  }

  function remove(Data storage self, uint value)
      public
      returns (bool)
  {
      if (!self.flags[value])
          return false; // not there
      self.flags[value] = false;
      return true;
  }

  function contains(Data storage self, uint value)
      public
      view
      returns (bool)
  {
      return self.flags[value];
  }
}
```

I have tried his to get the storage -

```
var startSlot = web3.toBigNumber(
    web3.sha3(web3.padLeft("0", 63)+pos, { encoding: 'hex' }));
var slot = "0x" + startSlot.add(n).toString(16);
var bn = web3.toBigNumber(slot);
var output =eth.getStorageAt(con.address, bn)
```

With:

```
pos=0
```

I am unsure exactly how the slot positions are worked out for a mapped struct. I know the sha is taken and the added to the position.

I tried this too -

```
key=n;
pos=web3.padLeft("0",63)+ "0";
 var slot = web3.sha3(key + pos, {encoding:"hex"});
 var bn = web3.toBigNumber(slot);
var output= eth.getStorageAt(con.address, bn)
decout=web3.toDecimal(output);
```

I only get zeros back for the outputs from this js.

Has anyone any idea how to locate the storage for the code given?

Comment: You said you're looking for the storage "on the disk," but you're not, right? You're just trying to inspect storage via `getStorageAt`?

Comment: I meant not memory.

Answer (score 0):

The storage location of a key within a mapping is given by:

```
keccak256(key . slot)
```

where `.` is concatenation. The `slot` in this case should be 0, so to find `knownValues[n]`, you want to look in:

```
keccak256(n . 0)
```

Both `n` and `0` should be encoded as `uint256`s. JavaScript code should be something like this:

```
var n = 0;
var loc = web3.sha3(web3.padLeft(n.toString(), 64) + web3.padLeft("0", 64), { encoding: 'hex' });
web3.eth.getStorageAt(con.address, location);
```

Comment: n=1 gives me some output (number 1 in final output). Everything is zero (n=2 etc). I added about 5 elements into the mapping. I am testing more now.

Comment: I don't know if you're trying to tell me this worked or that it didn't.

Comment: Neither, just a result that n=1 produces something. So using n=1 enables the getStorageAt method to address some data. But it is not evident if that data is an array element (it is just the number 1 shown in a lot). n!=1 provides all zeros. So I have more testing to do. I am mainly trying to test the efficiency of storage in Ethereum using arrays (eg deleting array members).

Comment: `n=1` should give you the value at `knownValues[1]`. If that's a member of the set, then it should return `0x000...1`. If it's not, then it should return `0x000...0`.

Comment: n=1 seems to work but nothing else. I am unclear at present exactly what is happening. But I want to store DB keys in Ethereum (or their hashes) and volumes could get very high. So understanding the storage efficiency is very important. That is main reason for me trying to test these storage allocations.

Comment: Well, it could be that the calculation is wrong? With your current code, each item stored will take one 32-byte word.

Comment: I am still trying to understand how the dynamic address works. I think the complication is what happens to array entries when there are structs and then what happens when there are mappings within a struct. I am testing still.

Comment: Your code doesn't have any arrays, and the struct only has one thing in it, so I believe this is all just the same as a regular old `mapping`.

Comment: I think, what I need to do is to understand how dynamic addressing works in Ethereum, rather that piecemeal examine every combination of storage which could happen. There are so many possible combinations that the principle is what really matters I think. Then it can be applied to any combination of storage options. I am therefore testing out different configs to see what results they bring.

Comment: FYI, I published a blog post this morning about storage and how locations are calculated: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/09/understanding-ethereum-smart-contract-storage/

Comment: I put that in my social media. I can presently working on how to use oracles and leveldb. The interest to me is how finally we can store key db information. That is why I think storage matters. So if we have IPFS for example, the issue is how we can access that securely and efficiently in ethereum. I think leveldb is critical to this but there is no web3 tool I understand for leveldb. So I am working on how to access it.